# SAT Math problem (key features of graphs)

Tags: graph-theory

Question: An indifference curve plots the amounts *x* of product X and the amount *y* of product Y such that the value to a consumer of the total amount of products X and Y for any point along the curve is constant. It has the property that *y* decreases as *x* increases. For one consumer, good X is flour, good Y is sugar, *x* and *y* are in pounds, and 5 pounds of flour alone have the same value as 3 pounds of sugar alone. Which of the following could represent the indifference curve in the *xy*-plane for this consumer?

How do I know the value to a consumer of the total amounts of X and Y on a curve? How do I know it is constant when I look at a graph? How do the points (5,0) and (0,3) as shown in the answer explanation show that 5 pounds of flour alone and 3 pound of sugar alone have the same value?

[image: Answer Choices (green is correct answer)]

[image: Answer Explanation]

Answer (score 1):

The first graph you show, (A), includes the points (0,5) (0 lbs of sugar and 5 lbs of flour) and (3, 0) (3 lbs of sugar and 0 pounds of flour). You know that every point on that curve have the same value to a consumer because you are **told** this curve is an "indifference" plot-  that this curve consists of (x, y) points such that  x pounds of sugar and y pounds of four have the same value to the consumer.

Comment: I think the problem I have is that take for example a point on the correct answer graph: (2, 0.75) about. How do I know that 2 pounds of flour and 0.75 pounds of sugar has the same value to a consumer as 5 pounds of flour and 0 pounds of sugar?

Comment: So this is a problem with the English language rather than the mathematics?  As I told you before, you know that because the problem **tells** you that!  You are told that al points on this curve have the same value to a consumer- that is what "indifference" means.

Comment: No, there could be an answer choice that isn't an indifference curve.